# Sync a local MySQL database and a live server MySQL database

Tags: mysql, php

I want to store data in my local MySQL database and after a time interval or when system connected to internet it will update my live MySQL database remotely. Is it possible?

I have an inventory management script in PHP MySQL. The problem is in our country internet connection drops suddenly. So, I want to first write to the local MySQL database and then it will update the real server. In any situation like internet connection dropped, the script will work locally to gather data and retrieve data. When the internet connection comes back it will update the data to the real server.

Other user will use the same system at the same time. That time, the real server will also be updated. So, when two database will merge, it will consider time and rearrange its invoice number and other things.

Comment: You'll probably run into way much problems here. How your databases will manage conflicts between your local database and the live server database (two Primary Keys created on each server) ? How will you manage two almost same changes on your local db and the local db of your other user ?